# MFMailComposeViewController doesn't close

Tags: ios, objective-c, email

I have an app where I use E-Mail to developer Button. When I press the button VEMailView-controller opens.
This is just wrapper for MFMailComposeViewController.

When I press "send" button, the controller have to be closed but I see just white window. No more. It must be closed to main ViewController. How to fix?

This is my code:

```
    #import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>

#import "VEMailView.h"

@interface VEMailView () <
    MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate,
    UINavigationControllerDelegate
>
// UILabel for displaying the result of the sending the message.

@end


@implementation VEMailView{
    BOOL alreadyOpened;
}



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    alreadyOpened = NO;

}
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[self showMailPicker];

}

- (void)showMailPicker
{

    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])

    {
        [self displayMailComposerSheet];
    }

}

- (void)displayMailComposerSheet 
{
    MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    [picker setSubject:@"iOS"];

    NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"first@example.com"];

    [picker setToRecipients:toRecipients];

    NSString *emailBody = @" ";
    [picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}

- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller 
        didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error
{

    switch (result)
    {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
            NSLog(@"Result: Mail sending canceled");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
            NSLog(@"Result: Mail saved");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
            NSLog(@"Result: Mail sent");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
            NSLog(@"Result: Mail sending failed");
            break;
        default:
            NSLog(@"Result: Mail not sent");
            break;
    }
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}



@end
```

Comment: `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];` =>`[controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];`

Comment: @Larme, no. It doesn't work.

Comment: I don't see any problem at here. Could you send your sample code? I tried your code but I dont see anything

Comment: Quick Question: Do you have a nav bar?

Comment: @Larme, no I have just empty ViewController

Comment: @VietHung. The idea is: 1. Open empty ViewController, 2. Send EMail, 3. Close at all automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my own solution.

To solve this problem change

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

into

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];}];
```

Thanks [Michal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23007703/1979882) for idea.

Answer (score 3):

That's because you are making an extra view controller. Create the `MFMailComposeViewController` in the view controller where the button is. The mail compose controller is a controller by itself. There is a white screen because that is the default view of YOUR `VEMailView`. Get rid of that and put these methods:

```
- (void)showMailPicker;
- (void)displayMailComposerSheet;
```

in the view controller with the button. Also make it the delegate.

Comment: This works. But it doesn't work automatically. You gave me brilliant idea how to do it automatically. I will write solution in my own answer. Thanks anyway. http://stackoverflow.com/a/23008141/1979882